# Buttons with rounded corners in android

Tags: java, android, xml

I would like to create buttons like the **Sign Up** and **Login** button [image: Heart link mockup]  I found the image on https://www.google.com/search?q=medicine&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiuyrO8koLMAhWlJ5oKHcRuDjgQ_AUICCgC&biw=1366&bih=697#tbs=isz:lt%2Cislt:svga&tbm=isch&q=stethoscope+%2B+laptop&imgrc=Uh8IGO8X6CBcMM%3A 
The methods that I have tried include using the following

1. Using a **Shape drawable**

The result so far has not been pleasant to look at.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To speed up the process I actually came across this tool that generate code for your xml http://angrytools.com/android/button/ After you have modified the button to your liking all the user just has to do is copy the xml generated code into their application. The tool has a lot of customisation options which include Size, Padding, Corners, Background, Padding and Stroke.

Answer (score 13):

Try this -

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="30dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/black"/>
 </shape>
```

Answer (score 1):

see this you will get exactly .

```
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="@color/green"/>
   />
<gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="@color/green" 
   android:endColor="#58857e"></gradient>
  </shape>
```

Comment: make on in drawable folder and use in your button